# How can I hide the username on a custom user-profile.tpl.php page?

Tags: theming

I'm making a custom user-profile.tpl.php page and want to put the "business name" field where the Title/Username normally occurs and print the username elsewhere.

The username doesn't appear in the list at:
Administration » Configuration » People » Account settings » Manage Display so I can't remove it there.

My guess is that I need to add some logic to page.tpl.php to not print it on user profiles and then I need to know the variable to add it to user-profile.tpl.php.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by disable field display property using `form_alter`

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'FORM_ID') {
  $form['account']['your_field_name']['#access'] = FALSE;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a custom  module

2) Put this code:

```
function formalter_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  switch ($form_id) {    
    case 'user_profile_form':
        hide($form['account']['name']);
       //dpm($form['#user']->field_full_name);
        $form['account']['name']["#attributes"]['placeholder']=t('Bussiness  Name');
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I approached it differently.

I first created a custom page--user.tpl.php file in which I removed the section that prints the title.

I then found the username variable and wrote a little snippet to print it under the business name (except in cases where the business name doesn't exist) in user-profile.tpl.php.

```
<?php 

$user_username = $variables['elements']['#account']->name;

if (isset($user_profile['field_business_name']) || array_key_exists('field_business_name', $user_profile)) { 

$user_business_name = $user_profile['field_business_name']['#items'][0]['safe_value'];
print "<h1>$user_business_name</h1>";
print "<b>$user_username</b>";
print "<br>";
}

else

print "<h1>$user_username</h1>";
print "<br>";

?>
```